# App shows only White screen when. Deployed to real device

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin forms project and it was working good and fine as I was testing on my emulator and on a real device. And suddenly, it gives a white screen when I deploy to a real device but works fine when I use an emulator. Can anyone help me ? I have deleted bin and obj folders , restarted the device and also reloaded the project and still the same. The project is for a client and it's due in few days

Comment: Can you rollback to a previous commit and see if it works? Then you can track down which change broke things.Here's a forum post that sounds similar: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/134993/xamarin-forms-android-blank-screen-in-release-but-works-fine-in-debug

Comment: I haven't been committing into a repo. So I do not know what to do. I have reversed until the last build and nothing.

Comment: Try the link and see if it helps. Sometimes xamarin development can be the most frustrating thing in the world. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I hope it does